# How to maintain local storage Value across browser in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I want to maintain local storage across browser in angular.Though local storage is working for browser specific, hence i am not able to maintain stored value across browser.How can we accomplish this in angular ?

```
   localstorage.setitem("authid","123")
```

Comment: if you means between `Chrome` and `Firefox` for example, then it is not possible with local storage and cookie.

Comment: what do you mean by "across browsers" ?